# ReactSelect rendering custom component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select

I am using ReactSelect in one of my forms:

```
<Select name='event-title' className="event-title" ref="stateSelect" autofocus optionsComponent={DropdownOptions} onInputChange={this.handleChangeTitle} options={this.state.titleResults} simpleValue clearable={this.state.clearable} name="selected-state"  value={this.state.selectedTitleValue} onChange={this.handleTitleChosen} searchable={this.state.searchable} />
```

I'd like to to render a custom `optionsComponent`:

```
optionsComponent={DropdownOptions}
```

By looking at the [example](https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select/blob/master/examples/src/components/CustomComponents.js), you are able to render a custom component so I have tested that:

```
const DropdownOptions = React.createClass({
    propTypes: {
        children: React.PropTypes.node,
        className: React.PropTypes.string,
        isDisabled: React.PropTypes.bool,
        isFocused: React.PropTypes.bool,
        isSelected: React.PropTypes.bool,
        onFocus: React.PropTypes.func,
        onSelect: React.PropTypes.func,
        option: React.PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    },
    handleMouseDown (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();
        this.props.onSelect(this.props.option, event);
    },
    handleMouseEnter (event) {
        this.props.onFocus(this.props.option, event);
    },
    handleMouseMove (event) {
        if (this.props.isFocused) return;
        this.props.onFocus(this.props.option, event);
    },
    render () {
        return (
            <div className={this.props.className}
                onMouseDown={this.handleMouseDown}
                onMouseEnter={this.handleMouseEnter}
                onMouseMove={this.handleMouseMove}
                title={this.props.option.title}>
                <span>Testing Text</span>
                {this.props.children}
            </div>
        );
    }
});
```

This should be rendering `<span>Testing Text</span>` before every child. But it is not. What am I doing wrong?

My end goal is to make my options display various data like this:
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The property is `optionComponent` not `optionsComponent` as you've written.

Comment: Thanks, quick question that is somewhat relevant: what is the best way to pass in more information to be rendered with each optionComponent. For example I have more information than just a `label` and a `value`. I would like to display meta data for each title (as per my image)

Comment: The `optionComponent` is passed a prop of `option` which should be the data object. Here is the src for the rendered option, https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select/blob/master/src/Select.js#L887

Comment: How can we add icon for the selected option in v2

Answer (score 10):

With **react-select V2** you can achieve this by accessing the `data` prop that is passed to the custom component you pass to the `components` props of your `<Select />`

```
const Option = (props) => {
  const {
    ...
    data,
  } = props
  return (
    <div ...>
      {`${data.firstName} - ${data.lastName}`}
    </div>
  )
}

<Select
    ...
    components={{ Option }}
    ...
  />
```

Answer (score 0):

From the upgrade of **react-select V2** and above you can achieve this by accessing the `prop` that is passed to the custom component you pass to the **components** props of your `<Select />` so you can still maintain the default behavior of the select component

from their documentation here https://react-select.com/styles#cx-and-custom-components

```
import React from 'react';
import { css } from 'emotion';
import Select from 'react-select';
import { colourOptions } from '../data';

const Option = (props: OptionProps) => {
  const {
    children,
    className,
    cx,
    getStyles,
    isDisabled,
    isFocused,
    isSelected,
    innerRef,
    innerProps,
  } = props;
  return (
    <div
      ref={innerRef}
      className={cx(
        css(getStyles('option', props)),
        {
          option: true,
          'option--is-disabled': isDisabled,
          'option--is-focused': isFocused,
          'option--is-selected': isSelected,
        },
        className
      )}
      {...innerProps}
    >
      {children}
    </div>
  );
};

export default () => (
  <Select
    closeMenuOnSelect={false}
    components={{ Option }}
    styles={{
      option: base => ({
        ...base,
        border: `1px dotted ${colourOptions[2].color}`,
        height: '100%',
      }),
    }}
    defaultValue={colourOptions[4]}
    options={colourOptions}
  />
);
```